# How powerful would this motor have to be?

Tags: motor

I’m attempting to make and electric barrow (like a wheel barrow) which needs to push up to 100 kg up fairly large hills. I’m assuming it needs to be 24 V but I don’t know what power (watts) or what ever it needs to be.

Could anyone help?

Additional information:

- Speed = 5 mph
- 20 % incline

Comment: Information missing: How fast (height per time) do you want to push? How much do you want to be able to accelerate? Can you give an estimation about friction? Only if you provide this information it is possible to tell what (mechanical) power you need. Then using some assumptions about the efficiency of an electrical motor (e.g. 80%)  it is possible to tell you how much electrical power it needs to have.

Comment: It needs to be about walking speed so like 5mph going up grass slopes. That’s all I can tell you :(

Comment: Still information missing: How steep is the hill (=inclination; or is the 5mph height miles per hour? I don't think so)? Don't you see that it makes a difference if the hills slope is almost level or perpendicular?

Comment: About 20% incline

Comment: Good. Now add all this information into your question so that all the info is in the one place. Next convert it to metric and your speed to m/s. Then work out what the vertical speed is going to be. We'll help you along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your limited information it's only possible to give an lower limit of the mechnical power needed (i.e. more is needed because you probably also want to accelerate your load and you will have some friction; both are not considered because of missing information; also since this is only mechanical power you still need to consider that the efficency of the electrical motor is less than 100%; so its electrical power needs to me more):

5 MPH = 5 * 1600m / 3600s = ca. 2.2 m/s

Since inclination is 20% you have 0.2 * 2.2 m/s = 0.44 m/s (height per time).
Power is work per time and work is force times length.
So Power is force times speed.
Force in this case is is weight; which is mass times gravitational acceleration (on earth ca. 9.81 m/s² = 9.81 N/kg)

P = 100 kg * 9.81 N/kg * 0.44 m/s = 981 * 0.44 Nm/s = 431 W

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the limited information :/

Comment: I would guess that you'll expend more than that at the wheel going up a perfectly smooth incline.  I'd figure out the torque you need *at the wheel* for that theoretically smooth incline, then double it.  Then I'd be sure to estimate the power loss in the motor and in whatever gear train you use to calculate the power and torque needed at the motor.

Comment: This would be like stepping  on the gas on your car gently and waiting for a xx seconds  to reach desired or a minute to reach full speed.  try kinetic  energy and torque need to reach speed in 5 seconds or tbd. It may  exceed 1Hp.